# @font-face vs Google Web Fonts

Tags: internet-explorer, font-face, antialiasing, google-webfonts

I've designed a site using numerous Google Web Fonts.  Unfortunately, on WinXP (IE6-8), some fonts seem overzealously anti-aliased, and lose visual definition & clarity.  No issues on any other browsers (Safari, Chrome, FF) on IE8 nor on any browsers on MacOSX.

**IE8 on WinXP (Over-zealous AntiAliasing)**

[image: IE8 on WinXP (Over-zealous AntiAliasing)]

**Chrome WinXP (Looks Good)**

[image: Chrome WinXP (Looks Good)]

So I'm considering using the equivalent fonts from [fontsquirrel.com](http://fontsquirrel.com).  What are the advantages/disadvantages of using @font-face as opposed to Google Web Fonts?  So far, from my experimentation, they look much better...

PS. does document.ready() get fired after @font-face fonts are loaded?

Comment: After a bit more investigation (thanks to your answer), I was able to track down the problem. I used the equivalent font-face font and it was only marginally better in IE8, (due to difference in font design I imagine). But the real problem was the MS filter used for generating a gradient. I'm using Compass code (generated by http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to create gradient background. The MS filters used for IE6-8 gradients cause the font to appear unclear. When I resort to an image background (sigh...) the font is nice and clear again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## There is no difference.

If you take a look at the back-end of Google Web Fonts, it uses `@font-face` in exactly the same way that everyone else uses it, including FontSquirrel and its `@font-face` generator. Nothing magic, nothing extra-special. It's the font itself that matters, and the browser's rendering engine.

You could try a different font, or you could use browser-specific stylesheets to solve that particular problem.

---

P.S. No, the `DOMContentLoaded` (jQuery `ready`) event fires after the DOM is loaded, as the name suggests. `load` may fire afterward, I'm not sure. Best not to rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

If  you want it to be exactly the same on all browsers use something like Cufon.

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/Demos

There is a comparison of them all in this article

http://www.nineteenfortyone.com/2010/06/cufon-vs-css3-vs-google-font-api/

Someone asking a similar question here >>

[@font-face vs Google Fonts vs Cufon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781165/font-face-vs-google-fonts-vs-cufon)